# Usage of HTTP/2, from a web developer's standpoint

Tags: http, http2

I'm very new to concept HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2, I'm wondering from a web developer perspective, do any of these has to do with us? Do we have to refactor our code in order to utilize HTTP/2? Or most of these has to do with the browser instead?

I understand that this may looks like a off-topic as too broad question, I've also done my own studies however unable to understand it from a web developer's point of view. Wondering if anyone can help shed some light?

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/http-1-1-vs-http-2-what-s-the-difference

Comment: not really. No refactor necessary. Obviously HTTP/2 brings more to the table like streams, so you have more tools at your disposal as a web dev

Comment: @sinanspd: One thing that caught my attention is regarding the HTTP/2 — Server Push, do we have to change the way we set our resources in any way?

Comment: The tl;dr version is that the push cache is handled by the browser and used by html tags and/or js functions such as <script> <link>, fetch() etc. Pretty much any resource based tag will automatically use it. Of course as the domain of web dev evolves, there will be things to be taken into account, but most of the time these are and will be handled by browsers and servers (apache, nginx etc.) maintainers. I know there are some edge cases such as certain single page applications but I doubt there is anything you can do about that, push cache is a protocol level feature after all